# Using WWW::Mechanize Credentials

Tags: perl, credentials, ntlm, www-mechanize

I am having trouble using the credentials agent for WWW:Mechanize to access and web scrape a site that requires NTLM authentication.  I read online that the credentials agent requires 4 arguments: a base, realm, username and password. I'm not sure what to use for the base or realm so an example of these would be very helpful.  When I run my code I get an error unauthorized on the line with the $url get.  Any help would be appreciated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


use WWW::Mechanize;

use HTML::TokeParser;


my $url= shift || "mywebsite.com";

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

$agent->credentials ( "proxy:port", '', 'domain/username', 'password' );

$agent->proxy(['https', 'http', 'ftp'], 'proxy:port');

$agent->get( $url );

print $agent->content();
```

Comment: This [link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=765651) has an example, and it also mentions that WWW::Mechanize must be v1.5.2, or later to use credentials

Answer (score 1):

It helps to read the documentation of the software you're working with. WWW::Mechanize overrides the [`credentials` method](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-credentials-username-password-) so that it also just accepts username and password. These are eventually passed through to Authen::NTLM.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, so the credentials method should only have two arguments? username and password?

Comment: Yes, WWW::Mechanize's credential's method says just that ... http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech->credentials(_$username,_$password_)