# Perl Mechanize with NTLM authentication

Tags: perl, mechanize, ntlm, lwp

I haven't seen examples of NTLM support with Mechanize. Does anyone know how we can make use of NTLM libraries with Mechanize? If not, does LWP do the job?

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 'keepalive' => 1 );

my $url = "http://URL/I/NEED/TO/ACCESS"; <---Requires NTLM authorization
my $username = "username";
my $password = "password";

$mech->credentials($username, $password);
$mech->get($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this

[Using WWW::Mechanize Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941016/using-wwwmechanize-credentials)

you need to make sure you;re using v1.5.2 or later of WWW::Mechanize and ultimately it will use Authen::NTLM

If you have a backslash in your real username then you will have to use single quotes or escape it

```
 my $username = "domain\\user";
```

Comment: That link doesn't describe how to use Authen::NTLM with WWW::Mechanize